# Finding if field has empty records using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I am trying to iterate all fields in a feature class/shape file to check for empty values. If there are empty records in any field, I would like to print that field.

I know Python a little bit and here is my attempt.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\SOFTWARE\Python\Jun2019"
fc ="test.shp"
##
fieldlist = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
##Iterate feilds
for field in fieldlist:
           # Iterate over each feature; if it has a non-null value
           with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
               for row in cursor:
                   if row[0]h=
```

I am stuck here.

How do I continue?

[image]

I want print fields TYPE,CAT,SUBTYPE etc. which are having empty values

Comment: `if not row[0]` should be true for empty string and `None`

Comment: @BERA Strangely `if not row[0]` does not flag `None` values in text fields. I'm not really sure why?

Comment: It does for me with file geodatabase input. (Are you sure the values are None and not a string 'None'?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches. I suspect the first approach is faster as it breaks out of the loop as soon as it finds a value in a search list:

**Approach 1: Classic Search Cursor**

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb\featureclass'

# Get a list of fields
fields = [x.name for x in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]

bad_list = []

for field in fields:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, field) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] in ["", None, " "]:
                bad_list.append(field)
                break

print bad_list
```

**Approach 2: Query Dictionary**

Here is another approach that queries a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) populated by a [Search Cursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm).

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to get a list of all the fields in the featureclass

```
fields = [x.name for x in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
```

Use a Search Cursor to populate a dictionary with unique values (`set()`).

```
d = {field: set(x[0] for x in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field)) for field in fields}
```

The resulting dictionary has the following structure:

```
{'Field1': ['A','B','C'], 'Field2': ['A', None, 'B'], 'Field3': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Now query the dictionary with the following search list `[None, "", " "]` and populate a list with the fields that contain items in the search list:

```
bad_list = [a for a, b in d.items() if any(w in b for w in [None, "", " "])]
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb\featureclass'

# Get a list of fields
fields = [x.name for x in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]

# Populate a dictionary where key = field and value = list of unique values
d = {field: set(x[0] for x in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field)) for field in fields}

# Query dictionary and return list of fields that contain an item in the search list
bad_list = [a for a, b in d.items() if any(w in b for w in [None, "", " "])]
```

Comment: Great. This works for me

Answer (score 0):

You could identify all of the rows where any of those fields are empty by including a where clause in your cursor:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field,'"TYPE" IS NULL or "SUBTYPE" IS NULL or "CAT" IS NULL') as cursor:
    for row in cursor: #only includes rows where at least one of the three are empty
```

The SQL query will vary depending on the dataset type and field types (The example above is looking for null values in a FGDB feature class).

Then you will only parse the table once.

Comment: NB:  The OP mentioned both feature classes and shapefiles.  Shapefiles cannot include NULL values.  So you would also need to check for `""` (empty string) for string fields and `0` (zero) for number fields, in addition to the check for NULL.

Comment: Great. This code works for me.